# Express a recurring temporary situation

Tags: expressions

I try to express the fact that I'm traveling a lot in a figurative way.
In french I would say "toujours entre deux voyages" ("always in-between two travels").

I have tried the following sentences but it looks weird:

- always coming from and going to travels
- always coming from and planing travels
- always looking for a connection flight

Comment: "Always coming or going" is an expression that comes to mind, though it's more often used in other (more literal) senses.

Comment: Jobs are referred to as "working to refill the cruising kitty/climbing kitty/backpacking kitty, as applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression *always [on the go](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/on%20the%20go)* has currency here.

On the go means constantly traveling or busy.

You could also say *always coming or going* which preserves the notion of being between two journeys from the French.